# Pain in knees, quadriceps, ankle on jogging

Tags: running, pain, legs, knees, jogging

I am an 80 kg guy, height 5'6", and I have been jogging for like 5-6 months now. Initially, I used to jog in a park, 1-1.5 km a day. Then I gained a lot of weight and didn't have time for jogging, but I have resumed jogging. My stamina increased, and I started running 4 km — this was on hills, with little slope up and down. My quadriceps hurt like hell initially, but the pain went when I stretched a little. Then I had a break for a month or so, and again I started running. I tried to increase my pace of running to 10-10.5 kph, but this decreased my endurance and I could only run like 2.25 km in 2 laps. Also, now my legs hurt. The first 1 km is easy, then I take a break, and the next 1 km I feel pain. I also feel the pain in day-to-day routine as well. I haven't stopped running, but I only run like 3-4 days a week now.

I want to know what actually is causing this pain, and what I should do now; I want to be fit and keep running, and increase my pace and stamina as well.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have actual running shoes, how often do you get new running shoes, and do you use them for anything else but running?

Comment: @JohnP I do not have some running shoes, just normal shoes, some daily wear stuff. And why is this question 'off-topic'?

Answer (score 3):

It could be something more complicated, but generally I'll just say that **running hurts**, especially when you're just starting or increasing your mileage.

I would recommend following a training program like [couch-to-5k](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_3/181.shtml). With something like that, the distance increase and schedule will be regulated. If you have excessive problems with pain or handling the workload, at least you know that you're starting with something proven.

When you invent your own running schedule, you introduce the variable of a bad schedule which can cause over-use injuries and generate rather poor results.